# Событие onError, как узнать ошибку?

Tags: события, javascript

Доброго времени суток! Использую JavaScript событие onError в тегах `<img>`:

```
< img src="test.ru/img1.jpg" onError="fc_error()">
```

Вопрос такой: как узнать статус ошибки, с которой было вызвано событие? То есть узнать, ошибка `"404 Not Found"` или `"net::ERR\_INTERNET\_DISCONNECTED"`. Мне главное узнать, ошибка была 404 или нет.

Подскажите, как узнать. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Наконец-то до меня дошло, что нужно получить именно код ответа HTTP запроса, при загрузке картинки, если все хорошо: 200, если все плохо, то типа: 404.

Ответ на Ваш вопрос: **это нельзя сделать**. Киньте в меня камень, если это можно сделать. Да и зачем, если есть удобные средства для этого?

Поэтому я не понимаю, почему Вам не подходят стандартные варианты, но Вы всегда можете их использовать: AJAX, GET, XHR, new Image, а также **ужасный inline script onerror**, чтобы проверять валидность загрузки картинок.

Собственно то, как мне кажется, что Вы не принимали предлагаемое мною, как вариант решения и есть вариант решения того, что Вам надо.

Comment: а я думал, что можно через js читать консоль

Comment: @PicanTo, да, при ошибке загрузки картинки в консоль пишется код ошибки, но во первых - это не кроссбраузерное решение, во вторых автору надо это делать через inline script, в третьих - это бред, ибо есть 1001 способ сделать это без извращений.

Comment: @PicanTo, если бы автор еще рассказал нафига ему это вообще надо, может быть я был бы не столь категоричен.

Answer (score 0):

Я в JS сильно не разбираюсь, но возможно, это то, что вам нужно: http://learn.javascript.ru/onload-onerror

Comment: Нет, это не то. Там не объясняют, как найти статус ошибки.

Comment: Как же не объясняют?  
В коллбэк передаётся сообщение об ошибке.